# StructureMap can not find a default instance for HttpServerUtility

Tags: c#, structuremap, ioc-container

I have a class that relies on `HttpServerUtilityBase` my plan was to get structure map to use `HttpServerUtilityWrapper` as the default instance. Nothing odd there. However, once I've added the declarations to my registry, structuremap is unable to resolve the instance and I get a 202 error.

This is my registry:

```
public class ApplicationRegistry : Registry
{
    public ApplicationRegistry()
    {
        Scan(scanThe =>
        {
            scanThe.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
            scanThe.WithDefaultConventions();
        });

        Scan(scanThe =>
        {
            scanThe.AssemblyContainingType<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
        });

        SetAllProperties(x =>
        {
            x.WithAnyTypeFromNamespaceContainingType<IFinancialYearRepository>();
            x.WithAnyTypeFromNamespaceContainingType<IUserManagementFacade>();
            x.WithAnyTypeFromNamespaceContainingType<IBulkTypeImporter>();
            x.OfType<ILog>();
            x.OfType<ISessionManager>();
        });

        For<IUnitOfWork>()
            .HttpContextScoped()
            .Use(() => new EFUnitOfWork(
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PublishedEFSqlServer"].ConnectionString
                    )).Named("publishedUnitOfWork");

        For<IUnitOfWork>()
            .HttpContextScoped()
            .Use(() => new EFUnitOfWork(
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UnpublishedEFSqlServer"].ConnectionString
                )).Named("unpublishedUnitOfWork");

        For<ILog>()
            .AlwaysUnique()
            .Use(s =>
            {
                ILog loggger;
                if (s.ParentType == null)
                {
                    loggger = LogManager.GetLogger(s.BuildStack.Current.ConcreteType);
                }
                else
                {
                    loggger = LogManager.GetLogger(s.ParentType);
                }

                if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    ThreadContext.Properties["user"] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                }
                return loggger;
            });

        For<ISessionManager>().Singleton();

        For<HttpServerUtilityBase>()
            .Singleton()
            .Use<HttpServerUtilityWrapper>();
    }
}
```

It all looks fine to me, but clearly I'm missing something. Also the line from the generated by calling `WhatDoIHave()` that refers to HttpServerUtilityBase seems to have a reference to `HttpServerUtilityWrapper` so I guess it should just work.

> ---
>
> HttpServerUtilityBase (System.Web.HttpServerUtilityBase)                                         3bf840df-e159-4dcf-93ef-211bb7484698                                                                                                       Configured Instance of System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   Scoped as:  Singleton

What am I missing?

Comment: FYI - you do not need to scan the assembly containing HttpServerUtilityBase. Scanning is only used to register types by convention. In this case, you are explicitly registering the HttpServerUtiltityBase type, so the convention scanning doesn't buy you anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the fix is simple. I need to specify the constructor argument for the `HttpServerUtilityWrapper`

```
For<HttpServerUtilityBase>()
    .Singleton()
    .Use<HttpServerUtilityWrapper>()
    .Ctor<HttpServerUtility>().Is(HttpContext.Current.Server);
```

Comment: For the ninjecteers:

            `kernel.Bind<HttpServerUtility>().ToConstant(HttpContext.Current.Server);`

            `kernel.Bind<HttpServerUtilityBase>().To<HttpServerUtilityWrapper>().InSingletonScope();`